# The command to open multiple tables in MapBasic

Tags: openlayers, mapbasic

I would like to know what commands/statement can open (or select) multiple tables in MapBasic?. Please show me?

Answer (score 1):

The syntax is:

```
Open Table "*<path of table>*"
```

For example

```
Open Table "C:\Temp\table1.TAB"
Open Table "D:\GISDATA\points.TAB"
```

etc

EDIT or to list open tables in a session use MapBasic:

```
Dim i as integer   
Dim j as integer
Dim TableArray(1) as String
ReDim TableArray(i)

i = NumTables()
 For j = 1 to i TableArray(j) = Tableinfo(j, TAB_INFO_NAME)
 Next
```

Comment: Thanks you! But i want open multiple tables at once (example: open table table1.tab and points.tab by one comand. Do you know?

Comment: You could write a function and pass a string variable to it with an array of table names...

Which would be much more work than just having a series of Open Table commands! :)

Is there a particular reason why you're trying to do this?

Comment: Thanks you, Mr. Morgan Ellingham. I'm a beginer. I'm trying to creat a legend table from multiple tables which tables i will select. So, the command to open multiple tables very important for my code. Thanks you so much.

Comment: So you want a table with all the names of the currently open tables in your session?

If so, you could use:

Dim i as integer
Dim j as integer
i = NumTables()
Dim TableArray(1) as String
ReDim TableArray(i)
For j = 1 to i
TableArray(j) = Tableinfo(j, TAB_INFO_NAME)
Next

Comment: I'll put it in as an answer, if it works let us know!